# openshift where is the unpacked waar file?

Tags: tomcat7, openshift

Using a new app on Tomcat 7 (JBoss EWS 2.0) cartridge.
Deployed a test.war by:
 git commit -m 'test.war'
[master bc58479] test.war
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 webapps/test.war
...

Then I se ethis in the application log:

```
2014-05-02 07:38:29,766 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.wiki.WikiEngine  - *******************************************
2014-05-02 07:38:29,772 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.wiki.WikiEngine  - JSPWiki 2.10.0 starting. Whee!
2014-05-02 07:38:29,775 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.wiki.WikiEngine  - Servlet container: Apache Tomcat/7.0.40
2014-05-02 07:38:29,994 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO org.apache.wiki.WikiEngine  - JSPWiki working directory is '/var/lib/openshift/$myapplicationkey/jbossews//tmp/JSPWiki-15458554'
2014-05-02 07:38:36,582 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.apache.wiki.PageManager  - An I/O exception occurred while trying to create a new page provider: org.apache.wiki.providers.CachingProvider
java.io.IOException: Failed to create page directory /var/lib/openshift/$myapplicationkey/jspwiki-files , please check property jspwiki.fileSystemProvider.pageDir
```

I tried to create "/var/lib/openshift/$myapplicationkey/jspwiki-files" and get permissions denied.

If the tes.war file was deployed, then I could set the location to some place I would have permissions but (Suggestions as to where it should be?)
BUT, I can not find where the jspwiki.properties file is deployed so I can change the location of the "jspwiki.fileSystemProvider.pageDir"

Thanks
-jim

Comment: What cartridges are you running?  How did you deploy the war file?  We need more information to be able to try to provide a helpful answer.

Comment: updated question with more information.